# How to use Firebase Cloud Functions with the new modular Firestore API?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have upgraded my Firebase v8 project to v9. The web application now uses the modular SDK with the new functional API for Firestore.

In this project I use Firebase Functions. There I have upgraded to firebase-admin 11.0.0. But it seams it does not provide the new functional API for Firestore.

```
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const app = initializeApp();

import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

This throws:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProvider')
  at Object._getProvider (/p/happygast/node_modules/@firebase/app/src/internal.ts:110:6)
  at Object.getFirestore (/p/happygast/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/api/database.ts:185:10)
```

Now I am not sure if I am doing something wrong? Or is there no functional Firestore API for Cloud Functions?

In essence: Is `firebase-admin/app` compatible with `firebase/firestore`? Or: How do I initialize and use `firebase/firestore` in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 3):

You are importing `initializeApp()` from the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin) but `getFirestore()` from the [Firebase Client SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) and then passing an instance of Admin SDK in it that's invalid. Instead, you should import Firestore from the Admin SDK itself as shown below:

```
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore'); // not firebase/firestore

// Initialize by ADC or another service account 
const app = initializeApp();

const db = getFirestore(app);
```

If you want to use the client SDK, then you'll have to initialise the  Firebase instance using the client SDK itself:

```
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase/app');
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase/firestore');

// use the web config that can be found in Firebase console
const clientApp = initializeApp({ ...config }); 

cpmst db = getFirestore(clientApp);
```

Comment: But can I use the client SDK in my Cloud Functions?

Comment: @Witek yes you can. just initialize as you would in a web app. It won't however have privileges of Admin SDK

Comment: Without privileges I wont be able to read/write Firestore. Is there a way around this? So that cloud functions have full access to Firestore?

Comment: @Witek you can use the Admin SDK itself in cloud functions then. Why are you trying to use client SDK?

Comment: I am using the same codebase for reading/writing firestore in my webapp and in my cloud functions. Since I dropped the v9 compat API in my code, I am unable to get my cloud functions running again. It seams I have to move back to v9 compat. :-(

Comment: @Witek I am not sure what you mean by "single codebase". Are you initialising Firebase in a file and using same in both web app and Cloud function? Then that's invalid. You should initialise Firebase in the functions separately.

Comment: I have code in a file which does business logic. Including the required access to Firestore. For example there is a function `checkXyz` which loads a document, checks some fields and then writes the check result back into the document. I want to use this function in my webapp and in my cloud functions. Therefor it must depend on the same Firesore API.

Comment: any info about this case ?